# Как Closure использовать вместо методa класса?

Tags: php, классы, замыкания, методы

Товарищи как написать код чтобы работал следующий пример без __get и __set.Все остальное можно.

```
class A {
    //Какой код тут написать ?
}

$a = new A();

$a->setName = function(A $a, $value)
{
    $a->name = $value;
};

$a->getName = function(A $a)
{
    return $a->name;
};

$a->setName('Vasya');
echo $a->getName();
```

Спасибо

Comment: Без __get и __set - значит __call использовать можно?

Comment: @Мелкий  Все что угодно кроме них

Comment: Название свойства и метода совпадают - если бы отличались, еще можно было бы наверное извернуться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Друзья я решил эту задачу

```
class A {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        try{
            if(property_exists($this,$name) && is_callable($this->$name)){
                $arguments = array_merge([__CLASS__=>$this],$arguments);
                return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $arguments);
            }
            else{
                throw new Exception($name.' is not a callable');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}

$a = new A();

$a->setName = function(A $a, $value)
{
    $a->name = $value;
};

$a->getName = function(A $a)
{
    return $a->name;
};

$a->setName('Vasya');
echo $a->getName();
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php#117504

Comment: Круто, отличное решение!